# Table updating - but report is empty. Reopening report shows correct data

Tags: vba, insert, report

Should be an easy one for the experienced?

I collect data from multiple other tables and do calculations in VBA with which I add rows with `DoCmd.RunSQL` to a printout table. (Before this, I delete previous printout rows.)

After this I do a `db.Close + Set db=Nothing`, then display a dialog whether to preview or print. Upon selecting Preview, the report is shown, but it's empty. (As in, all the labels are there, there are 0 rows of data, and all the other data fields are blank.)

The report associates printout rows with the current user, so it's valid to "just open" the report, and then it shows the correct data.

If I keep the table open while running, I can see the `DELETE FROM` taking effect ('##Deleted##' or something similar), but I can't see `INSERT INTO`s taking effect until I re-open the table.

I use no connection, I use `Dim db as dao.Database` + `Set db=CurrentDB`; data is written to a local (non-linked) table; there's nothing special in the query (sort of, `SELECT field1,field2... FROM mytbl WHERE user=currentuser`) the report is based on; there's no code module for the report.

What's going on here, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boy, am I feeling stupid now. I copied the DoCmd.OpenReport line from an identical report that used another table as data. The problem is, when I changed it to have an OpenArg, I had too few commas and it unnoticably ended up being a "filter". Code hinting is there for a reason... oh well :)